# Need help with Integration Using Substitution?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm having trouble integrating: $\displaystyle \int\frac{x^{2}+2}{x+1} \ \mathrm{d}x$

I set U equal to $\displaystyle x+1$ and $du=1$. I get to the step $\dfrac{(u-1)^{2}+2}{u}$
  . What should I do next?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expand the numerator, and divide each term by $u$: $$(u - 1)^2 + 2 = u^2 - 2u + 1 + 2 = u^2 - u +3$$

This gives $$\int \dfrac{u^2 - 2u + 3}{u} \,du = \int \Big(u - 2 + \frac 3u\Big)\,du$$

Now, just integrate each term.

Comment: Nice clear hint +1

Answer (score 2):

Actually the substitution is not required:
$$
 \frac{x^2+2}{x+1} = \frac{x^2- 1 + 3}{x+1} = x-1 + \frac{3}{x+1}
$$